# Visual Studio 2013 debugging doesn't end cleanly with Firefox or Chrome

Tags: asp.net, firefox, visual-studio-2013

I have an ASP.NET MVC project in VS 2013. If I debug (F5) and Firefox is selected (next to green play button) it works but when Firefox shuts down Visual Studio remains in debug mode.

I have to either a) Shift-F5 to end the debug session, or b) exit IIS Express from the system tray.

If Internet Explorer is selected, everything works as expected and the debug session ends when IE is closed (and IIS Express keeps running, which I don't mind).

I've verified that the firefox.exe process is quitting when its browser window is closed. Same problem when Google Chrome is selected.

How can we have Visual Studio end the debug session gracefully when firefox.exe quits?

Answer (score 0):

I may be related to Edit and Continue new functionality, to disable it:

1. Open properties for web project
2. Select Web tab
3. Uncheck "Enable Edit and Continue" in the "Debuggers" section

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Nope enabling/disabling Edit and Continue makes no difference